# R: fill out a new colum based on sevaral variables in another dataset

Tags: r, loops, match

I have a first dataframe with 4 columns (ID, Year, X and Y)

```
Id Year    X     Y
1  2017  20_24
1  2016  45_49
2  2017  30_34
2  2014  20_24
4  2014  14_19
4  2015  20_24
```

I would like to fill out the Y column using another dataset.
The second dataset got the same variables ID and year, the other columns are the items of the column X in the first dataset.

```
Id Year    14_19   20_24   30_34  45_49
1  2017     123    122     5555    4444
1  2016     456    543     8888    333
1  2015     5644   0908    0987    5456
1  2014     5642   767     233     323
2  2017     123    123     5666    989
2  2016     456    876     55      45
2  2015     786    789     324     77
2  2014     633    543     334     34
3  2017     123    123     321     44
3  2016     456    345     45645   23
3  2015     876    4556    6554    23
```

So I would like Y to be filled out when ID, Year and items of the X variables are matching the columns of the second dataset.How is this possible ?
Thanks !

Comment: share your current approach or what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

result <- df2 %>%
  gather("X", "Y", -c("ID", "Year")) %>%
  right_join(df1, by = c("ID", "Year", "X"))
```

Or with the use of `pivot_longer()`

```
result <- df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 3:4,
               names_to = "X",
               values_to = "Y") %>%
  right_join(df1, by = c("ID", "Year", "X"))
```

Comment: good solution. You should look into `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` insead of `gather`

Comment: @AndS. Good point. I've seen `gather()` is retired, but couldn't get myself to switch to it, since `gather()` is still used on the platform when I am learning R.
I've added also `pivot_longer()` version of this solution.